# How to create a UserControl that you can drop other controls in it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

In WinForms, how can I create a `UserControl` that when I put on my form I can then add other controls inside by dragging them from the toolbox, the same way as with all containers controls (panels, group boxes, etc)? I've tried to add controls by dropping them in my control but then when I move my control the controls I added stay right where they are, which wouldn't happen if instead of my control I would use a `Panel` (the other controls would move with the panel).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unlike a `Panel` control for example, a `UserControl` does not act as a container control once it is placed on another form. There is full design-time support while you are designing the `UserControl` itself, but its default behavior does not allow it to act as a constitutent control after it has been placed on another form. This is why you are unable to add other controls to it by dragging them from the toolbox.

In order to add this type of behavior to a `UserControl`, you need to add the [`DesignerAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerattribute.aspx) to the definition of your custom `UserControl` class. For example:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;

[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner, System.Design", typeof(IDesigner))]
public class MyUserControl : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
    //...your code here
}
```

(See the relevant [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813450) article for further reading.)

If you want to implement full designer support for *nested* controls inside your `UserControl`, this is slightly more difficult. For a more comprehensive discussion, see [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/NestedControlDesigner.aspx) on CodeProject.